# Transform a base 64 encoded string into a downloadable pdf using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a django/python3 application that requests the Limesurvey API and gets a base 64 encoded string as result.
I'd like to return this result as a downloadable pdf file.

Here's my current implementation that's simply display the base 64 string into a blank page...

```
    data = limesurvey.export_responses_by_token(survey_id, token)
    response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/pdf')
    return StreamingHttpResponse(response)
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three steps:

### Dump your base64 content into StringIO

```
import cStringIO as StringIO
buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
content.decode('base64')
buffer.write(content)
```

### Send response with proper header

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

# generate the file
response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(buffer.getvalue()), content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=MY_FILE_NAME.zip'
return response
```

### Configure your server

Beyond the scope of django.

e.g. for nginx, refer to [this link](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/)

### Update

After testing your content in some [online converter](https://www.base64decode.org/), I'm sure that's base64 stuff.

However, the reason why it doesn't work remains unknown until further information is provided.

My mock snippet is like this.

```
>>> test_str = 'test'
>>> base_64 = test_str.encode('base64')
>>> base_64.decode('base64')
'test'
>>> base_64
'dGVzdA==\n'
```

Comment: Thanks! I can download the file with your solution indeed. Although, the content.decode('base64') doesn't work. I get this error "'str' object has no attribute 'decode'". It's seems that the string is already considered as decoded but it's isn't. Hence the downloaded file is corrupted...

Comment: @epi.log you can paste some of your content here.

Comment: the downloaded pdf file weight 114KB.
Here's an extract (beginning) 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